# UV unwrapping issue, UV map appears as cube

Tags: texturing, uv

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eExpP.jpg

[image]

I am working on modeling a Formula 1 car. I am almost done modeling the car, but I am running into a problem with UV unwrapping.

The body of the car is modeled off of a cube that has been extruded, cut, shaped, etc. with Blender's modeling. The wheels are modeled off of cylinders. It can be seen in the image I put here that when UV unwrapping the car, the UV map is not clean with lots of overlaps and extremely bad crowding and you can't tell which vertices in the map correspond to which vertices on the model. Interestingly you can clearly see the outline of an unwrapped cube, assumedly the body of the car, while the wheels are pretty clear.

Wondering how I can get a cleaner UV map which I can work with for texturing. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You'll need to apply the scale to your model in Object mode (Ctrl-A) and mark some seams before unwrapping it. Plenty of YT tutorials on UV unwrapping online.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good! John Eason is right, you just need some seams for your unwrapping to go right. With a model like this that shouldn't be too hard, there are many edges that can be used as seams. To make a seam, make a selection of edges and press ctrl+E, then select 'Mark Seam'. This will mark those edges in red and tell Blender that when UV-unwrapping the faces that share this edge cannot be connected in the UV-map. That way you can separate the UV-map into islands, like you're looking for. Here's this [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS6B5PAzlWI) by Royal Skies who has done lots of tutorials on Blender. Or "Blendeh", as he likes to call it.

Good luck!